# Moving correlation

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have two arrays:

```
A = 1:20
B = 101:120
```

I want to find the moving correlation. i.e.

```
CorrMat(1) = corr( 1:15, 101:115 );
CorrMat(2) = corr( 2:16, 102:116 );
CorrMat(3) = corr( 3:17, 103:117 );
CorrMat(4) = corr( 4:18, 104:118 );
```

And so on.

I can write a for loop for that but is there a smarter way to do it ?

My definition of correlation is same as of Matlab corr. All I am trying to do is obtain a moving window of it.

Comment: The MATLAB `corr` function returns a correlation *matrix*, You seem to look for a *single value*. What is your definition for "correlation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `arrayfun`:

```
A = 1:20;     %// First array, same numel() as second
B = 101:120;  %// Second array, same numel() as first
W = 1:15;     %// Window indices, always starting with 1

CorrCell = arrayfun(          ...
  @(k) corr(A(k+W), B(k+W)),  ...
  0:(numel(A)-numel(W)),      ...
  'UniformOutput', false      ...
);
```

For contrast purposes, I'll write the loop-based implementation:

```
N = numel(A) - numel(W);
CorrLoop = cell(1, N+1);
for k = 0:N
        wnd = k+W;
        CorrLoop{k+1} = corr(A(wnd), B(wnd));
end;
```